# .extend changes value into NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using a backbone model to retreive some data.
Within my view I have a config object which I would like to extend with the data in my model.

Now almost (yes almost) everything is going according to plan.
Except for one value in the object which goes from 100 to NaN.

To extend the object I use `jQuery.extend`.
The data is correct before the extend, after it is NaN.

Here is the code:

```
extendData: function () {
    var opt = this.model.get('Data'),
    $.extend(this.config, opt);
},

config: {
    circleThickness: 0.08,
    animationTime: 2000,
    textSize: 1,
    labelSize: 0.5
}
```

This is the data in the model.attributes.Data:

```
minValue: 0,
maxValue: 100,
value: 42,
displayUnit: true,
unit: "%"
```

This is the object when I console log it after the extend:

```
{
    circleThickness: 0.08,
    animationTime: 2000,
    textSize: 1,
    labelSize: 0.5
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: NaN,
    value: 42,
    displayUnit: true,
    unit: "%"
}
```

As you can see the maxValue is now suddenly NaN...

I already tried the following:

```
this.config = $.extend(true, this.config, opt);

this.config = $.extend({}, this.config, opt);

this.config.extend(opt);

this.config = $.extend(this.createConfig(), opt);
createConfig: function () {
    return {
        circleThickness: 0.08,      // The outer circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
        innerCircleThickness: 0.25, // The inner circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
        circleFillGap: 0.05,        // The size of the gap between the outer circle and wave circle as a percentage of the outer circles radius.
        animationTime: 2000,        // The amount of time in milliseconds for the transition to take place.
        textVertPosition: .5,       // The height at which to display the percentage text withing the wave circle. 0 = bottom, 1 = top.
        textSize: 1,                // The relative height of the text to display in the wave circle. 1 = 50%
        labelSize: 0.5             // The relative height of the label text to display outside the circle 1 = 25%
    };
}
```

Now I just tried creating a variable, and then placing this value in the variable and it works. When I want to put this information in the backbone view it delivers.. a NaN again. Here is the code to explain my gibberish:

```
//declared config
config: {},

//changed config to basicConfig:
basicConfig: {
    circleThickness: 0.08,
    animationTime: 2000,
    textSize: 1,
    labelSize: 0.5
}

//changed function to:
extendData: function () {
    var opt = this.model.get('Data'),
    var config = $.extend({}, this.basicConfig, opt);

    console.log(config); //this shows maxValue = 100

    this.config = config;
    console.log(this.config); //this shows maxValue = NaN

}
```

So when I put the data in the backbone view... it changes from 100 to NaN?

Here the way the data is retrieved in the model.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.getData();
}
getData: function () {

    var self = this;
    var key = this.get('itemKey');

    var data = {
        name: globals.name,
        key: key,
        isFunction: this.get('itemIsFunction').toString().toLowerCase() === 'true',
        latitude: app.location.get('latitude'),
        longitude: app.location.get('longitude')
    };

    this.fetch({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        //dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: data
    });
}
parse: function (response) {

    if (response) {
        var utcPublishdate = new Date(response.PublishDate);

        var day = utcPublishdate.getDate();
        var month = utcPublishdate.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months are zero based
        var year = utcPublishdate.getUTCFullYear();
        var hour = utcPublishdate.getUTCHours();

        var minute = ('0' + utcPublishdate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
        response.PublishDate = (day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
        response.PublishTime = (hour + ":" + minute);

        if (response.Data && !_.isObject(response.Data)) {
            response.Data = JSON.parse(response.Data);
        }

        if (response.DataTile && !_.isObject(response.DataTile)) {
            response.DataTile = JSON.parse(response.DataTile);
        }
    }

    return response;
},
```

What is causing this issue? 
And how can I prevent it?

All help will be appreciated

Comment: Without delving deeper needlessly, have you tried it with a deep copy?  `$.extend(true, this.config, opt);` ?

Comment: tnx will try it immediatly.... (waiting for answer).... nope doesn't work.
Will edit my post, since I found something else, it might just be Backbone ding some nasty things....

Comment: Figured it was worth a shot.  I don't see anything glaring at me so without more information, best guess would be what's coming in from your model.

Comment: see my changes, when I put the data into the view is where it goes wrong..

Comment: how are you fetching your model ?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/atnm07zr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/atnm07zr/1/) and when I added the latest backbone from [http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js](http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js) the console gives me errors dealing with backbone's extend.  Perhaps this is part of the problem?

Comment: Nevermind it's retard hour, I forgot to include underscore...

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/atnm07zr/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/atnm07zr/3/) -- I haven't been able to replicate the error thus far, so I'm back to either what's coming in from your model or some other section being the offender.

Comment: This is really breaking my balls. can't see why this should happen. 
@FrançoisRichard I use jsonp to get the data with a model fetch.

Comment: @spynix it's really weird indeed, never had this before.

Comment: this fiddle does work. but the model attributes are not retreived with jsonp http://jsfiddle.net/atnm07zr/13/

Comment: provide code for fetchign please

Comment: @FrançoisRichard See topic, I placed the code for fetching,

Comment: What is the output if you call `console.log(opt);` before the extend call?

Comment: But nevermind peepz thanks for all the help. I found a work around which works at least in this case.

Comment: That's not very satisfying.

Comment: no its not, but with a deadline it's something to deal with in times with less stuff to do ;)

Comment: what versions of jquery / backbone are you using ?